# Inverse Function of Logarithm

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, exponential-function

[image]

The answer is A but I don't understand why!

$ -2 \log_e (x^2) $ can be re-written as $ -4 \log_e(x) $ right?

but why do these two graphs look different?

the graph $-2 \log_e (x^2) $ is one to one from $ x > 0 $ or $ x < 0 $... why $-1$?

Comment: No, $\log_e(x^2)$ cannot always be rewritten as $2 \log_e(x)$. This can only be done when $x$ is positive.

Comment: $-4 \log_e(x)$ is not defined for $x<0$, so on the domain $(-\infty,-1]$ the function is $f(x) = -4\log_e(-x)$. If both $x$ and $-x$ are included in the domain then both will have the same image under $f$ which means $f$ cannot be invertible. Also note that $f$ isn't defined at $0$.

Comment: what do you mean when x is positive? 

oh and yes i get the 0 issue. if there was an option such as

x < 0 then this would also be correct right?

Comment: For a negative $x$, $\log x$ is undefined, so $\log(x^2) = 2\log x$ cannot possibly be true.

Comment: oh yes! i see... 

if the domain was [m, infinity) could i have applied the power rule and re-written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hint:

the function should be

1. defined so $x\ne0$
2. one to one and onto so either $(-\infty, 0)$ i.e $m<0$ or $(0,\infty)$

Comment: yup, i see it! thanks.. :)

Comment: Glad to help out, moreover, i improve it, do you accept it.

Comment: yes! :) i get it now. thank you